# timer class does not seem to work

Tags: c++, std

Im having problems with my Timer class im trying to make,

For some reason it seemed to work when i did not have it nested in a class, But as soon as i tried to add it to a class it stopped working.

It is called inside a std::thread.

endTime and startTime both = 1.52426291e+09
elapsedTime is always 0

```
class Timer
{
public:
    Timer::Timer()
    {
    }

    Timer::~Timer()
    {
    }

    void Timer::init()
    {
        m_StartTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
    }

    void Timer::update()
    {
        m_EndTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
        elapsedTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(m_EndTime - m_StartTime).count();
        m_StartTime = m_EndTime;
    }

    float Timer::getElapsedTimeInSec()
    {
        return this->elapsedTime;
    }

private:
    float elapsedTime;
    std::chrono::duration<float> m_StartTime;
    std::chrono::duration<float> m_EndTime;

};
```

Comment: Remove all those `Timer::`. They are only needed on member function definitions outside of the class. Also, you can safely remove the empty ctor&dtor.

Comment: Also, next time please include the exact error messages.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat the `Timer::` are only there because i copied it from my cpp file to put it into one file.

Comment: @wihutamiz Post a [mcve].  A class by itself does nothing.  Code that uses the class provides the proper context.  As it stands now, default constructing your `Timer` class leaves all of those members uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

Declare m_StartTime and m_EndTime as time-points ( not durations ). You missed comverting milliseconds to seconds during elapseTime calculation. Here's a snippet with implementation .

```
class Timer
{
public:
    Timer::Timer()
    {
    }

    Timer::~Timer()
    {
    }

    void Timer::init()
    {
        m_StartTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    }

    void Timer::update()
    {
        m_EndTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        elapsedTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(m_EndTime - m_StartTime).count()/1000;
        m_StartTime = m_EndTime;
    }

    float Timer::getElapsedTimeInSec()
    {
        return this->elapsedTime;
    }

private:
    float elapsedTime;
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point m_StartTime;
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point m_EndTime;

};

int main()
{
    Timer timer;
    timer.init();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    timer.update();
    std::cout << timer.getElapsedTimeInSec() << " sec\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]